# Java Mail - Best Practices/Efficient way to create an email notification system

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, weblogic12c

I'm writing a system which sends email notification to users once a work has been assigned to them.

As you can imagine "establish a connection to the mail server " is expensive.

I would like a way to reuse the same connection. The problem is that the mail server at some point will "**kill**" the connection (because of inactivity etc).

Also I don't want to create a `Session` object every time I send an email... the same session object should be used.

Here is how my EJB method looks like:

```
@Asynchronous
public Future<String> sendEmail(String email) {
   .....
   //I want to reuse the same session object. What if another
   //application runs in the same JVM and creates the session
   //object before mine? My properties will be ignored? Probably Yes.

   Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
   try{
       // Instantiate a message
       Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
       .....
       //This will create and close the connection each time...
       Transport.send(msg);
      }
   finally{....}
}
```

Comment: What about using a transactional mail service like Mandrill?

Comment: @Raffaele my company doesn't want to pay/use third party products. Anyway it would be good to have in SO a best practice for such a common task.

Answer (score 2):

You can reuse the Session object, but you'll need to figure out the best place in your application to create it and store it for reuse.

Likewise the Transport object, but as you point out your application will have to deal with the fact that the mail server doesn't want you to keep the connection open if you're not doing anything with it, and so will close the connection.  You'll need to reconnect when you detect this.

If you're sending a high volume of email, you'll probably want to send all the notification requests to a separate thread or task or whatever and send the email from there.  You might want to batch up the notifications and send them out every day or hour or minute or whatever is appropriate for your application.

As you can see, there is no one best practice for dealing with all these issues.  It depends a lot on the needs of your application.

Comment: Is it possible to keep a pool of connections open in Weblogic? That would be ideal (I think). The email has to be sent as soon as a "job" has been assigned to a person(the receiver of the email). There may be 100 in a second (my estimate).

Comment: There's nothing that keeps a pool of connections open.  If you're sending 100 messages a second, the server shouldn't be timing out the connection because it's idle!  If you don't get acceptable performance using a single connection, you'll need to manage your own pool of connections.  Since a connection can only be used by a single thread, you'll want to send all your requests through a single component that can manage the connection (Transport object).  You might want to use JMS to queue the notification requests.

Comment: the 100 mail per second is just e peak estimate. It may well happen that for 6 hours or 12 hours no job is created and assigned. I'm trying to figure out what's the best way to tackle this scenario. Since you are the principal developer for Java Mail, I think it would be a good idea to have some lines of code that tackle this scenarios with performance in mind. 10 lines of code speak more than a 100 slides sometimes...

Comment: As I said, the right answer depends much more on your application, its structure, its requirements, etc.  A simple approach might not scale, and a scalable approach might be more complex than is justified by your application requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can read more about sending emails: https://mailtrap.io/blog/sending-email-using-java/

My solution for this case is: Just write your session Factory like hikari or others. It will close connection when necessary, or create as well. If many requests came one after another, it will keep the same connection alive.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34866061)

Comment: @RubioRic: I’m not a fan of this approach for an answer, either, but it does provide more than just a link, since it offers actionable advice on at least one solution. That said, the author would do well to [edit] the answer to offer more details and better summarize content of the link.